# Confusing \n behavior with white-space: pre

Tags: html, css, newline, whitespace, caret

**Why is it that a `\n` only creates an actual new line inside a `contenteditable` with `white-space: pre`, if there is something following the `\n`?**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ4hL/2/)**

Various examples in the fiddle. The first `contenteditable` has a text node inside with a single `\n` character. My expectation would be that this creates two lines inside the `div`, since the `\n` character should begin a new line, even if there is nothing on that new line. This is more so confirmed by the fact that a container with nothing at all inside looks exactly the same as a container with a single new line.

The next two boxes also both have a single `\n`, but both are followed by either text or `\r`, so a new line is created. The example with `\n\r` is the only one which produces logical behavior for me, as there is no text in the box, but there is still one extra line created by the `\n`.

Overall, it looks to me as if the usage of `\n` always produces one less new line than I would expect. When inspecting the element with Chrome's inspector, you can see that the closing `</div>` is pushed to the next line -- so why is there no new line in the `contenteditable`?

**Background information, if relevant**

I am building a `contenteditable` input field similar to Twitter's tweet publish input which highlights characters that go over the limit.

One of the issues to tackle is line break behavior and in order to make it cross-browser compatible (including IE8), I have decided that the most appropriate solution in my case is to `preventDefault()` event on pressing the `RETURN` key, and manually add an `\n` instead of letting the browser add a random HTML tag. In order for these `\n`s to be visible, my `contenteditable` div is styled with `white-space: pre`.

This technique also requires manually moving the caret one position forward, which is where my issue with `\n` not showing up as a visible character comes from. I can add a `\r` after the `\n` to ensure a visible line break appears, but this messes up my character count.

Comment: Your character count is probably messed up anyway.  This is because the '\n' is two characters 0x0a,0x0d on DOS/Windows systems, 0x0a on MAC systems and 0x0d on unix like systems. so the results will vary depending on which system is being used.